# Como verificar se uma String completa outra?

Tags: javascript, jquery

gostaria de saber se existe alguma função ou operador que pode verificar se uma String se parece com outra no javascript por exemplo:

```
var str1 = "joao foi ao mercado";
var str2 = "joao fo";
```

O que eu preciso é comparar a primeira com a segunda, se a segunda for um pedaço da primeira então retorna true (tipo o like do mysql)

Comment: Dê uma olhada https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Ou ainda essa pergunta no SO em inglês que descreve o % de similaridade https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473745/compare-strings-javascript-return-of-likely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str1 = "joao foi ao mercado";
var str2 = "joao fo";

if ( str1.contains(str2)  ) 
    //é parrte
else
    //não é parte
```

Aqui tem várias outras maneiras https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript

Answer (score 3):

Uma opção é usar o método [`String.prototype.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search). Se o retorno é `-1` não existe, caso contrario é porque existe. Veja:

```js
var str1 = "O menino joao foi ao mercado";
var str2 = "joao fo";

function compare(str1, str2){
    return (str1.search(str2)>0)? true : false;
}

console.log(compare(str1,str2)); //true
```

Se preferir também, outra opção seria usar expressão regular. Para este caso retornará `false` ou `true` podendo a *string 2* estar em qualquer parte da *string 1*. Veja:

```js
var str1 = "O menino joao foi ao mercado";
var str2 = "joao fo";

var rx = new RegExp(str2);

console.log(rx.test(str1)); //true
```

Tem também o [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
var str1 = "O menino joao foi ao mercado";
var str2 = "joao fo";


console.log(str1.includes(str2));  // true
console.log(str1.includes("joac"));  // false
```

Answer (score 1):

Seria uma opção usar *[indexof](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)* e fazer sua própria função?

```
function ContemString(str1, str2){
    return str1.indexOf(str2) > -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O método [**search()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/tbc7a78k(v=vs.94).aspx) Localiza a primeira correspondência da subcadeia de caracteres em uma pesquisa de expressão regular.

```js
var str = "joao foi ao mercado",
substring = /joao fo/;

var pos = str.search(substring);
console.log(pos);
```

```js
var str = "joao foi ao mercado",
substring = /joao não fo/;

var pos = str.search(substring);
console.log(pos);
```

```js
var str = "joao foi ao mercado",
substring = /fo/;

var pos = str.search(substring);
console.log(pos);
```